# how to insert into one array and then the other? (parallel array help)

Tags: c++, arrays

i am trying to use parallel arrays. When i perform the first iteration to capture employee name I can enter and then the hours. The second iteration it skips the employee name capture. It proceeds to the hours to be captured and the rest of the hours
I am trying to capture employee[1] name and then hours[1] of said employee.

/*
parallel arrays
*/

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 5;
int main()
{
    string empName [SIZE];
    int hours[SIZE];

 

    int index = 0;
    for (index; index <= SIZE-1; index++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the Employee " << index +1 << " name: ";
        getline(cin,empName[index]);

        cout << "\nEnter the Employee hours:  ";
        cin >> hours[index];
    
        
    }
        
}
```

Comment: Don't use "parallel" arrays. Make a struct for an employee and then use a std::vector<employee>. Don't use the "C" style arrays you're currently have.  With a std::vector you can add as many employee structs as you need by using push_back. May I ask where you are learning C++ from?

Comment: I am learning from a textbook. Starting out with programming logic and design 4th edition.

Comment: So not a dedicated C++ book then ;)

Answer (score 0):

The approach you should take with C++ is this

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

// using namespace std; <== no unlearn to use this

struct Employee
{
    std::string name; // use std::string for strings.
    unsigned int hours; 
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Employee> employees;

    while(true)
    {
        Employee new_employee; 
        std::cout << "Enter employee name (use `end` to end input) : ";
        // note I left out input validation for brevity
        std::cin >> new_employee.name;
        if (new_employee.name == "end") break;

        
        std::cout << "Enter employee hours : ";
        std::cin >> new_employee.hours;

        employees.push_back(new_employee);
    }

    // use a range based for loop
    // employee should not be modified by the loop so const
    // Employee& is a reference (avoids struct from being copied)
    std::cout << "\n You entered the following information : \n";
    for(const Employee& employee : employees)
    {
        std::cout << "Name = " << employee.name << ", hours worked = " << employee.hours << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see new include directives that i have not used before, aside from <iostream>. I see your comments about namespace std. Will look into that. 

Also the textbook I am using, starting out with programming logic and design. Do you perhaps have any recommendations?

Comment: <chrono> was not needed (but I typed it because of hours). All these headers are part of the standard library for C++. This is the place where you should look for more information : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/standard_library

Comment: Good sources to learn C++ from are a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) (make sure it is up-to-date and not teaching you "C", books tend to age quickly). Or you can use  [learncpp.com](https://learncpp.com/). Also make sure to check [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) to explore what C++ has to offer (containers/algorithms). 
And finally refer to the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) to learn how C++  is intended to be used.

Comment: This is an interesting video [stop using using namespace](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZqjl9HEPZ8) from C++ weekly